# Suborder parents and children by age with CTE

Tags: mysql, postgresql, recursion, common-table-expression

After trying to find a proper solution for this problem and almost pulling all my hairs out I decided to come and ask for help.

**The Problem:**
I have a table with 4 columns that looks like this:

```
id | family_id  | parent_id | age   |
-------------------------------------
 1 | 1          |   0       | 45    |
 2 | 1          |   7       | 23    |
 3 | 1          |   0       | 59    |
 4 | 1          |   5       | 12    |
 5 | 1          |   1       | 27    |
 6 | 1          |   7       | 18    |
 7 | 1          |   1       | 30    |
 8 | 1          |   1       | 32    |
 9 | 1          |   6       | 9     |
```

Using a CTE I find out who the children are of a parent and sort them by a path that is linked to the parent. Like so:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (id, path, family_id, parent_id, age) AS (
   SELECT id, array[id] AS path, family_id, parent_id, age
        FROM test
        WHERE parent_id=0 
        AND family_id=1

        UNION ALL

        SELECT test.id,
               cte.path || test.id,
               test.family_id,
               test.parent_id,
               test.age
        FROM test
        JOIN cte ON test.parent_id = cte.id
)
SELECT id, path, family_id, parent_id, age
FROM cte
ORDER BY path;
```

the result, a nice table that is ordered by a parent and its children.

```
id | path     |family_id   | parent_id  | age   |
-------------------------------------------------
 1 | 1        |   1        |   0        | 45    |
 2 | 1,2      |   1        |   1        | 30    |
 3 | 1,3      |   1        |   1        | 27    |
 4 | 1,4      |   1        |   1        | 32    |
 5 | 5        |   1        |   0        | 59    |
 6 | 5,6      |   1        |   5        | 12    |
 7 | 5,6,7    |   1        |   6        | 9     |
 8 | 5,6,7,8  |   1        |   7        | 18    |
 9 | 5,6,7,9  |   1        |   7        | 23    |
```

---

Now comes the real challenge (too many hairs pulled out...)
How should my query look like so that it **also** sorts every parent (and linked children) by age (highest age first)?

The final result should be something like this:

```
id | path     |family_id   | parent_id  | age   |
-------------------------------------------------
 1 | 5        |   1        |   0        | 59    |
 2 | 5,6      |   1        |   5        | 12    |
 3 | 5,6,7    |   1        |   6        | 9     |
 4 | 5,6,7,8  |   1        |   7        | 23    |
 5 | 5,6,7,9  |   1        |   7        | 18    |
 6 | 1        |   1        |   0        | 45    |
 7 | 1,2      |   1        |   1        | 32    |
 8 | 1,3      |   1        |   1        | 30    |
 9 | 1,4      |   1        |   1        | 27    |
```

This solution doesnt work:

```
ORDER BY path, age;
```

---

A demo is provided in SQL Fiddle:
[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/328ac/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one isn't that elegant, but seems to work:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (id, path, family_id, parent_id, age, sort_col) AS (
        SELECT id, array[id] AS path, family_id, parent_id, age, array[age, -id]
        FROM test
        WHERE parent_id=0 
        AND family_id=1

        UNION ALL

        SELECT test.id,
               cte.path || test.id,
               test.family_id,
               test.parent_id,
               test.age,
               cte.sort_col || test.age || -test.id
        FROM test
        JOIN cte ON test.parent_id = cte.id
)
SELECT id, path, family_id, parent_id, age, array_append(sort_col, 999)
FROM cte
ORDER BY array_append(sort_col, 999) desc, path;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/328ac/109

Create a column (array) like you did it with the `path`, but use `age` instead of `id`. For the path `5,6,7` this column would be `59,12,9`. For ties you should also append the `id` (or `-id` - depending on if you want the lower or the higher one come first). Now the columns would be `59,-5,12,-6,9,-7`. Last step: append `999` in the main statement - This way the parent node will always come before the child nodes (assuming that no one is older than that (-: ).

The result is:

```
id | path    | family_id | parent_id | age | array_append
---|---------|-----------|-----------|-----|---------------------------
 5 | 5       |         1 |         0 |  59 | 59,-5,999
 6 | 5,6     |         1 |         5 |  12 | 59,-5,12,-6,999
 7 | 5,6,7   |         1 |         6 |   9 | 59,-5,12,-6,9,-7,999
 9 | 5,6,7,9 |         1 |         7 |  23 | 59,-5,12,-6,9,-7,23,-9,999
 8 | 5,6,7,8 |         1 |         7 |  18 | 59,-5,12,-6,9,-7,18,-8,999
 1 | 1       |         1 |         0 |  45 | 45,-1,999
 4 | 1,4     |         1 |         1 |  32 | 45,-1,32,-4,999
 2 | 1,2     |         1 |         1 |  30 | 45,-1,30,-2,999
 3 | 1,3     |         1 |         1 |  27 | 45,-1,27,-3,999
```

Note that I select `array_append(sort_col, 999)` only for demonstration reasons. You can remove it from the SELECT clause.

Comment: this solution solved my problem. Thanks for the added explanation of the code

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (id, path, family_id, parent_id, age, parent_path, root_age) AS (
  SELECT id, array[id] AS path, family_id, parent_id, age,
     NULL::integer[] as parent_path, age as root_age
    FROM test
    WHERE parent_id=0 
    AND family_id=1

  UNION ALL

  SELECT test.id,
           cte.path || test.id,
           test.family_id,
           test.parent_id,
           test.age,
           cte.path AS parent_path,
           cte.root_age AS root_age
    FROM test
    JOIN cte ON test.parent_id = cte.id
)
SELECT id, path, family_id, parent_id, age, parent_path, root_age
FROM cte
ORDER BY root_age DESC, coalesce(parent_path, path), parent_path IS NULL DESC, age DESC;
```

Sorry for my raw answer.

For the solution need a path without self id. This is the "parent_path" field.
With this column the sorting is simple now.
The exceptions are the rows without parent_path, that is, the root, where parent_path is null. For ordering this, need coalesce() and parent_path is null desc.

To order the root elements you need a "root_age" field. This should start the ORDER BY clause.

Comment: You may want to consider editing your answer to include a description of your code to let other users better understand your solution.

Comment: Getting very close, but not perfect. The sorting should be the other way around (high to low, instead of low to high). Is it possible to fix this in your example?

Comment: Thx for the quick update. The root (rows without parent_path) are still sorted low to high (should also be high to low)